# Android app crashing when it wasn't running

Tags: android, crash

Sometimes my Android app crashes randomly, when it was not previously open. I get a message that says, "Unfortunately, <app> has closed." However, it was already closed, usually for a significant period of time before this crash occurs. I use a crash reporting service but these crashes are not reported, so I have no clue what's going on.

I have seen this happening to other apps (that were not my own) in the past, so I thought this would be an issue I could easily google, but I can only find results related to crashes while the app IS running.

Any ideas as to why this might happen or resources to point me in the right direction would be much appreciated :)

EDIT: I am not asking anyone to fix this crash or determine WHY it's crashing. I know very well how impossible that is without any logs. I am just asking what, in theory, *might* cause an app to crash while it was not running.

Comment: do you have the error's log? please post it.

Comment: "However, it was already closed" -- please explain **precisely** what you mean by "closed". If you mean that you simply switched to another app (e.g., pressed HOME), then your process is still running. Beyond that, without a [mcve], it will be difficult for anyone to give you specific advice.

Comment: @RBesar No, I don't have the error logs. The crash happens at unpredictable times, and by the time I can retrieve the log, it's so cluttered that I can't find the error.

Comment: @CommonsWare By "closed" I mean closed. Not just in the background. The app was exited and not running.

Comment: Using generic terms like "closed" and "exited" is not helping. One can argue that neither concept *exists* in Android, let alone that there is a standard definition for what those terms mean. It would be much more helpful if you explained **precisely** what you are doing. For example: are you pressing HOME? Are you pressing BACK? Are you bringing up the overview screen/recent-tasks list and switching to another app? Are you moving to another app via some other means? Are you terminating the process through your IDE or the command line? Any of those might qualify for "closed" or "exited".

Comment: Are you have function that get data from api or anything else, but (maybe) it not handle yet for null exception?. 
if have faced problem like this, crash unpredictable. it because i not handle yet for null data and network available status.

Comment: @RBesar I appreciate your brainstorming possible causes. Unfortunately, this one can't be it either - I don't pull data from any API. It's a pretty simple Cordova application.

Comment: Same issue, if I reset my phone, I will intermittently have various apps, almost never the same, report crashes, when they haven't been opened for months, e.g. Polytopia, NFL Mobile, FB messenger, etc. I cannot find anything to go off of.

Answer (score 0):

Its difficult to say why it might be happening without a log, but a way to find it would be to use android monitor on android studio and see any kind of suspicious logs which could indicate why this might be happening. Also you need to be familiar with android debugging tools in order to debug this. A more general reason could be a system background service that might be running and waiting for results. Some pointers to check :

1. If using GCM, check if implementation doesnt cause any unchecked
   exception.
2. If using receivers in manifest, check none causes any
   unchecked exception.
3. If using alarmmanager in any way, check for any
   unchecked exceptions.
4. If using application level methods detecting
   app closure such as onTrimMemory or onTerminate, check any unchecked
   exceptions.

Comment: Because this happens hours or days after the app was last running, I don't know if using the android monitor would be feasible. I am familiar with android debugging tools, but because I have no way to predict or reproduce the issue, I don't have any real way to use them.